# Values in a pandas Series are missing after iterating through it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After I iterate through a Series in pandas, the values are missing. The code and output is below. I am printing a list of the values from the Series `'SaleCondition'` and then I am iterating through the Series and performing actions. How can I iterate through the Series without losing the values? The issue I am having is that iterating through the Series even initially omits all the values in the Series. I don't know why this: `print('SaleCondition', X_train['SaleCondition'].values.tolist())` doesn't print out anything in the iteration of the Series.

```
print('SaleCondition', X_train['SaleCondition'].values.tolist())
```

output:

```
SaleCondition ['Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Alloca', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'AdjLand', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'AdjLand', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Alloca', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Alloca', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Abnorml', 'Alloca', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Alloca', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Alloca', 'Abnorml', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Alloca', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Family', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'AdjLand', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Abnorml', 'Abnorml', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Partial', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal']
```

```
for i in X_train.columns:
    if i == 'SaleCondition':
        print('SaleCondition', X_train['SaleCondition'].values.tolist()) # <-***line in question***
    X_train[i] = X_train[i].astype(str)
    X_train = pd.merge(X_train[X_train[i].str.contains('nan') == False], X_train)
    X_valid[i] = X_valid[i].astype(str)
    X_valid = pd.merge(X_valid[X_valid[i].str.contains('nan') == False], X_valid)
```

output:

```
SaleCondition []
```

below is `X_train.columns`:

```
Index(['MSSubClass', 'MSZoning', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'Street', 'Alley',
   'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'LotConfig', 'LandSlope',
   'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle',
   'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'RoofStyle',
   'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st', 'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType', 'MasVnrArea',
   'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation', 'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond',
   'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinType2',
   'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'Heating', 'HeatingQC',
   'CentralAir', 'Electrical', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF',
   'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath', 'HalfBath',
   'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'KitchenQual', 'TotRmsAbvGrd',
   'Functional', 'Fireplaces', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType', 'GarageYrBlt',
   'GarageFinish', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond',
   'PavedDrive', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF', 'EnclosedPorch', '3SsnPorch',
   'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'PoolQC', 'Fence', 'MiscFeature', 'MiscVal',
   'MoSold', 'YrSold', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition'],
  dtype='object')
```

Comment: What's the point of `X_train = pd.merge(X_train[X_train[i].str.contains('nan') == False], X_train)`? Won't that drop a bunch of rows with the default inner merge?

Comment: _"... and performing actions."_  What is your intended action?

Comment: it would be easier to reproduce your problem with the data (or at least a part of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that each row of *X_train* contains *NaN* in some column between *MSSubClass*
and *SaleType*.

Note that in your loop *merge* instruction actually drops rows containing
*NaN* in the respective column.

To create the source test DataFrame, run the below code:

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).astype(float).reshape(-1, 4),
    columns=['MoSold', 'YrSold', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition'])
X_train.loc[0, 'MoSold'] = np.nan
X_train.loc[1, 'YrSold'] = np.nan
X_train.loc[2, 'SaleType'] = np.nan
X_train.loc[3, 'YrSold'] = np.nan
X_train.loc[4, 'MoSold'] = np.nan
```

The result is:

```
   MoSold  YrSold  SaleType  SaleCondition
0     NaN     1.0       2.0            3.0
1     4.0     NaN       6.0            7.0
2     8.0     9.0       NaN           11.0
3    12.0     NaN      14.0           15.0
4     NaN    17.0      18.0           19.0
```

Then, after all columns before the last one have been processed,
all rows of *X_train* have so far been deleted.

To confirm this, run the following loop (a slight modification of your code):

```
for i in X_train.columns:
    print(i, X_train.index.size)
    if i == 'SaleCondition':
        print('SaleCondition', X_train['SaleCondition'].values.tolist())
    X_train[i] = X_train[i].astype(str)
    X_train = pd.merge(X_train[X_train[i].str.contains('nan') == False], X_train)
```

The result is:

```
MoSold 5
YrSold 3
SaleType 1
SaleCondition 0
SaleCondition []
```

So as you see from the row for *SaleCondition*, *X_train* contains **no rows**.
And this is why *X_train['SaleCondition']* is (now) empty.